# php passing array between pages

Tags: php, moodle

I have two php pages running in Moodle.

index.php and lib.php

there is an include statement inside index.php pointing to lib.php.

inside index.php I have this function call;

> $users = get_mentor_users2($fromdate, $todate);

when I call the function, which executes in lib.php, I get a blank webpage.

The function in lib.php is:

> function get_mentor_users2($fromdate = 0, $todate = 0){
>
> //global $USER, $CFG;
>
> /*if(!$sumpcat = get_config('','sumname')){*/
>     ////if(!$sumpcat = get_config('','sumname')){
>     /*if(!$sumpcat = "summative"){*/
>         //echo $sumpcat;
>         ////error('Summarative Grade Category Name not Specified 1.','conf.php');
>     ////}
>
> $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT u.id , u.firstname, u.lastname
>     FROM {mdl_role_assignments ra}, {mdl_user u}, {mdl_course c}, {mdl_context cxt}
>     WHERE ra.userid = u.id
>     AND ra.contextid = cxt.id
>     AND cxt.contextlevel =50
>     AND ( roleid =3 )
>     AND u.firstname LIKE '%mentor%'";
>
> if($datesql = generate_sql_range2($fromdate, $todate, 'g.timemodified'))
>     {
>         $sql .= " AND $datesql";
>     }
>
> //get all users who graded
>      //echo $sql.'
> ';
>      //$users = $DB->get_records_sql($sql);
>
> //foreach
>
> //~ $tmpdata = array();
>    //~ $tmpdata = $DB->get_records_sql($sql);
>     //~ return array($tmpdata);
>
> //return $DB->get_records($sql, array $params=null, $limitfrom=0, $limitnum=0);
>
> $arr= array();
>      return $arr=$DB->get_records_sql($sql);
>      //return  $sql;
>
> }

Now here is the really odd part. Like above it fails and the screen stays blank, but when I embed the sql query inside the index.php page it executes just fine.

> $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname
>   FROM mdl_role_assignments ra, mdl_user u, mdl_course c, mdl_context cxt
>   WHERE ra.userid = u.id
>   AND ra.contextid = cxt.id
>   AND cxt.contextlevel =50
>   AND ( roleid =3 )
>   AND u.firstname LIKE '%mentor%'";
>
> $data = array();
>
> $data = $DB->get_records_sql($sql);

and the data is accessible.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: I may need to update this question

Answer (score 0):

you have `';` before your commented code:

```
'; //$users = $DB->get_records_sql($sql);
```

Comment: This should be a syntax error and you have to set the debug mode to developer to get the correct error messages other than the blank screen. To turn on debugging, go to  Administration->Developement->Debugging. Then select the "Developer:Extra developemnt messgaes for developer" and select the display debug messages.

Comment: Sorry new to stackoverflow. Syntax was correct in my original page. Problem is that the populated array will not pass between two pages, but I can pass the unprocessed sql string.

Comment: For some reason my code is not line breaking when I edit it here.